# Failed to resolve endpoint: jetty://http://localhost:8888/sample due to: No component found with scheme: jetty

Tags: apache-camel, jetty

I am trying to use jetty component with apache camel and simply print a "Hello World" message.
But I am encountering a error which says -> **Failed to resolve endpoint: jetty://http://localhost:8888/sample due to: No component found with scheme: jetty**,
Even though I have added dependency for jetty in my pom.xml. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Below is my code and pom file

```
package com.rama.example;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class JettyGreeting {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/sample")
    .log("Received a request")
    .setBody(simple("Hello, World"));


}
}); 
while(true)
    context.start();
}

}





<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
 4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-rest-expose</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jetty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
</project>
```

Error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[From[jetty:http://localhost:8888/sample] -> [L... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: jetty://http://localhost:8888/sample due to: No component found with scheme: jetty
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.start(DefaultModel.java:356)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.startRoute(DefaultModel.java:330)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultModel.java:323)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultModel.java:302)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.AbstractModelCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(AbstractModelCamelContext.java:326)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2679)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.lambda$doStart$2(AbstractCamelContext.java:2527)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(AbstractCamelContext.java:2544)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2525)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2421)
    at com.rama.example.JettyGreeting.main(JettyGreeting.java:26)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: jetty://http://localhost:8888/sample due to: No component found with scheme: jetty
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:834)
    at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:367)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:112)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 4):

You have camel-jetty as test scoped in the `pom.xml` file. Remove that so jetty is part of your application.